# WPF find column index of textblock inside visual tree

Tags: wpf, textblock, visual-tree

I want to calculate  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFUhv.png)  automation id of text block inside the content presenter. My visual tree looks like this-

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper`to determine any control in visual tree.
There are two helpful methods

> System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(DependencyObject reference)

to go up in tree hierarchy

> System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChiled(DependencyObject refernce, int childIndex)

to go down in tree hierarchy
See more: [VisualTreeHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper)